# I am attempting to place two columns beside each other in a row in bootstrap, but they keep stacking. Suggestions?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am unable to get the columns to align next to each other. Instead, they are just stacked on top of each other.

```css
.col-sm-4{
  background-color: black;
  opacity:0.9;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute
}

.container-fluid{
  padding: 0;
}
.row{
  margin: auto;
}

.col-sm-8{
  background-color: darkred;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class=" col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">


          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-10" >


          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: ?? why position absolute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` in the classes `.col-sm-4` and `.col-sm-4` and you're done.

Here you can see the result: https://jsfiddle.net/yz96fgje/

Comment: The problem with this is I have a background image that I also want them to stack over. The cols will not display without 'position:absolute'.

Comment: Then you should add that to your question as I was not able to sniff that. I was just trying to help you with the issue with the given information. Add the relevant code in the question then. If you want to keep the absolute, you may try ```left: 33.33%;``` on the ```.col-sm-8``` class. This won't be the mostbeautyful solution though. To be able to make it pretty, we will need your code. https://jsfiddle.net/jsura4q5/

Answer (score 0):

just a quick note that **Bootstrap 4 is a mobile-first design**. So `col-xs-2` doesn't work. Instead, use `col-2` which will apply it's effect from `0px` till the next breakpoint you make such as `col-sm-4` in your case.

Also, you don't need extra CSS you can just delete it. Remember that `col-xs` does not exist in bootstrap 4.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-2  col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
      hi 1

    </div>

    <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 col-lg-10">

      hi 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```